# How correctly edit users profile and store it's photo?

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload, registration

I have simple profile edit HTML form for users:

```
Username  [        ]
Email     [        ]
Password  [        ]
Photo     [ browse ]

[submit]
```

I know that I should store links to images in database, but how should I upload photo correctly? There will be up to 500,000 users.

Should I create folder for each user? Or should I create folders like `0-999`, `1000-1999`, and so on..? Or store all photos in one folder?

In many websites I've seen path like: `www.somesite.com/user-profile/cv/17523` or `www.somesite.com/edit-cv-17523/personal-details`

So that means for each user is created separate folder where It's photo is stored?

How about photo naming? Should I rename photo to user id like `17523.png`?

Comment: where are you storing the images?

Comment: you can store photos in month wise folder, and also you can rename the photo to user id to remove conflicts.

Comment: There often is no direct relation between how pictures are stored and their url's. Think a bit about security. I tend to store pictures in folders of a 1000, so folder `00000000-00000999` for the first 1000 and so on. But I haven't tested other variants.

Answer (score 0):

The best way depends up on how data you have based on the data your process will change.

There are 2 ways to store user images.

1. Putting binary data in database.
2. Storing in file system.

If you choose database then the advantage of not requiring any sort of filesystem permissions on the webserver. But the time taken to retrive image from database is increases if you have huge database.

If you choose file system then the file system has the added advantage of making retrieval extremely quick and efficient. Its been clear if you maintain a folder for every user

```
ex: profileimages/userID/photo.jpg
```